# NotificationCenter networking between swift class and objective -c Viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

In my objective C class , I have added below code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notify" object:nil];
```

In my Swift  class , I have added below code

```
NotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:(DataProcessingMethod), name:@"" , object: nil)
```

But unfortunately not working,What is wrong with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be like this :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(DataProcessingMethod), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:(DataProcessingMethod), name:@"" , object: nil)
```

Did you add an observer for the exact notification name, because there is no name in the observer @"Notify"